# Removing Star Rating View From Product Page

Tags: product, configurable-product, product-attribute

The issue is about my product page, I want the 5 starts at the right buttom in my product page not to be seen. How can I remove it to be seen on the right but still be seen in the review part as in the picture?

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfsqN.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL0MF.png

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using the Infortis Ultimo theme for your store and have made a lot of customizations to it. This issue is not occuring in the default Ultimo theme so it must be related to your own customizations. The ratings box that you want to remove is in the `my_sub_con` div class. Try to locate it and remove it.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the answer, the code that I found in view.phtml is below, is it the right place, how should I change it: <div class="container2-wrapper">
         <div class="my_sub_con <?php echo $my_sub_con_cls; ?>">
            
     <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true); //reviews ?>
     
     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls'); //alerts ?>

Comment: Backup your file first and then delete `<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true); //reviews ?>`. This should remove the Star Ratings Box from this position of the page.